# Force autocorrect on last word of uncontrolled React Native TextInput before submit

Tags: react-native

How can I force autocorrect to apply to the last word of the input before clearing the input, given that the TextInput **is** [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) for performance reasons? The input is submitted by tapping a custom button.

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={setText}
  ref={textInputRef}
  />
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to force autocorrect to apply before clearing, you could use the onSubmitEditing prop to call a function that would apply the autocorrect and then clear the input.
You can find more information about the onSubmitEditing here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={setText}
  ref={textInputRef}
  onSubmitEditing={() => { autocorrect(); clearInput(); }}
/>
```

The autocorrect() function could use the textInputRef to get the input value and apply the autocorrect as needed.

Comment: The key function here is `autocorrect()` which you've left out of the code. Also I have a different button which is not part of the keyboard which can also be used to submit the TextInput so onSubmitEditing would not be called in that case